# Should CiviMail report show bounces when using the Mandrill extension?

Tags: civimail, civireport, mandrill

Drupal 7.36 - CiviCRM 4.5.8 - Mandrill Transactional Emails 1.5

The system is correctly putting a hard bounce contact on hold, the soft bounce is not yet on hold. But I am not seeing the bounces reported by Mandrill on the report bounces.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is that both the MTE extension *and* Mandrill are properly configured. For instance, are soft bounces configured to be returned to CiviCRM?  See here for instructions on configuration:  https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte

I believe bounces are passed on to CiviCRM's standard bounce processing. You may need to check that the bounce reasons and soft bounce thresholds are correctly set (need to do a little mysql magic for that though).

Remember that contacts are not put on hold until the soft bounce threshold is met.

Comment: Thanks Dave - The extension does pass on the bounces correctly. So to answer my own question. No, it is not the expected behaviour. 

I was able to verify this on a test instance. Now I need to figure out why a particular site is not doing it correctly even though it seems to be set-up correctly.